# Valores duplicados cuando agrego un join - PGSQL

Tags: postgresql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Necesito agregar valores a una query.
Esta es mi consulta original que retorna 4 filas:

```
select histories.*, services.*, providers.name, califications.id as 
    calification_id, califications.rating from histories
    left join califications on histories.id = califications.history_id
    inner join services on histories.service_id = services.id
    inner join providers on services.provider_id = providers.id
    where histories.user_id = ?
```

Pero tambien necesito obtener providers.image y promotions.discount, pero esta query me retorna filas duplicadas, 20 filas para ser exacto.

```
select histories.*, services.*, providers.name, providers.image, 
  califications.id, califications.rating, promotions.discount from histories
    left join califications on califications.history_id = histories.id
    inner join services on histories.service_id = services.id
    inner join providers on services.provider_id = providers.id
    inner join promotions on promotions.provider_id = providers.id
    where histories.user_id = ?;
```

Probe usando un join con subselect y logre reducir los resultados a 12 XD.
Aqui el diagrama de

Adjunto el diagrama de las tablas en cuestion.

Comment: ¿Has probado con `DISTINCT`? Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo.